# Is total variation $\mu(\cdot) \mapsto |\mu|(\cdot)$ Borel measurable from $M$ to $M$?

Tags: reference-request, measure-theory, measurable-functions

Let $M$ be the space of finite signed measures on $\mathbb{R}$, equipped with the topology of weak convergence of measures. I would like to know if taking the total variation of a measure is a measurable operation with respect to this topology. That is, is $\mu \mapsto |\mu|$ a Borel measurable map from $M$ to $M$?

I have read [When do Borel $\sigma$-algebras generated by the total variation norm and the weak* topology coincide?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/204707/when-do-borel-sigma-algebras-generated-by-the-total-variation-norm-and-the-we) where it is mentioned that $\mu \mapsto ||\mu||$ is Borel measurable in a similar setting, but no proof or reference is given. A reference would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: In the **norm** topology of $M$, yes.  Which is enough for proving $\mu \mapsto \|\mu\|$ is Borel.  In fact, that map is even **continuous** for the norm topology.   But in the weak* topology?  Doubtful...